# How to stop an .MSI installation Using a wix custom action

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I'm making some checks before the installation with a Custom Action. I want it that the installation will not start if these checks fail.

Is there a way to do this gracefully?

Comment: What sort of checks are you doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your checks can not be done using `Condition` element then in your Custom Action you should return `ActionResult.Failure` if your checks fail or return `ActionResult.Success` if the checks pass.

Returning Failure should cause your setup to go in RollBack mode and it will not progress any further. This will work if the `Return` attribute of [CustomAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) element is set to `check` which is the default.

Comment: I'l try this later thanks. For the moment all I was doing was forcing an exception and letting windows handle it. This isn't a safe of doing things I assume?

Comment: If the exceptions don't stop your msi from execution then it won't be safe. It might also cause a dialog to popup with an exception message during the installation. Returning `Failure` however will make sure that your setup is rolled back and whatever was installed until that point will be removed.

Comment: I would also suggest to have a look at `Condition` elements. You can use these to check for things like presence of certain application or versions of your or third party software.

Comment: WiX DTF custom actions have a top level try{}catch{} block that gets invoked before your static method gets invoked.   If you throw an exception,  it'll be caught and logged to the windows installer log (assuming you are logging)  and ActionResult.Failure will automatically be returned.  That said,  I would still author my own error handling and implement a single point of return pattern.